# How to return xml as text inside element

Tags: java, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<MyElement>
   <Request xsi:type="myDto" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <id1>Zyk226DvtvGLiLMPeN7x6/U=</id1><id2>Zyk226DvtvGLiLMPeN7x7/U=</id2>
   </Request>
   <Code>XXX</Code>
   <Version>1.0.0</Version>
</MyElement>
```

How can I get the xml returned as text which is inside element Request ? So for this example I want it to return `<id1>Zyk226DvtvGLiLMPeN7x6/U=</id1><id2>Zyk226DvtvGLiLMPeN7x7/U=</id2>`

I try to use DocumentBuilder but with no success:

```
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(xml);
            String response = doc.getElementsByTagName("Request").item(0).getNodeValue();
```

it returns null but I want it to return `<id1>Zyk226DvtvGLiLMPeN7x6/U=</id1><id2>Zyk226DvtvGLiLMPeN7x7/U=</id2>`

Comment: I don't think you can extract the tags too (i you want to extract

Comment: Possibly because there is nothing worth returning in Request. What you do want is the information stored in id1 and id2, so try accessing these nodes instead of the Request-node.

Comment: @avk I really dont need information inside id1 or id2 because request contains another xml which I want to extract

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can extract the `<id1>` or `<id2>` tags directly without implementing you own parser.

But you could extract the value inside your tag and surround it with your tags' name by using `XmlReader` class

[Quick example on how to use XmlReader](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader)